# Can not perform Groupby on pandas dataframe of memmap arrays because it's unhashable

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-memmap

I have panada dataframe `predictions` which consists of three columns. I created this dataframe using three `memmap array`.

```
    predictions = pd.dataframe{'cell': list_1, 'tree': list_2, 'predict': list_3, 'label': list_4}
```

Now I wanna groupby on two columns of this dataframe and average on third column as follows:

```
    df = predictions.groupby(['tree', 'cell'])['list3'].mean()
```

But it gives me the error which says the memmap array is unhashable! and it can not perform `groupby`.
I really need to do `groupby` otherwise I have to do two `for` loop which takes forever because  my dictionary has `1,000,000` rows. I'm wondering does anybody know the solution? Thanks

**Edited**
`cell` and `tree` columns are lists of items from`memmap array`. `predict` and `label` are  just normal lists.
The list of `memmap array` items looks like:
cell

```
[memmap([415], dtype=int32), 
memmap([143], dtype=int32), 
memmap([96],  dtype=int32), 
memmap([432], dtype=int32), 
memmap([104], dtype=int32), 
memmap([76], dtype=int32), 
memmap([312], dtype=int32), 
memmap([143], dtype=int32), 
memmap([312], dtype=int32), 
memmap([64], dtype=int32),
memmap([296], dtype=int32)]
```

The prediction dataframe is look like this:

```
      cell  label  predict  tree
0    [415]      0        1  [19]
1    [143]      1        1  [22]
2     [96]      0        1  [19]
3    [432]      1        1  [12]
4    [104]      0        1  [21]
5     [76]      0        1  [19]
6    [312]      1        1  [22]
7    [143]      1        1  [22]
8    [312]      1        1  [22]
9     [64]      0        1  [18]
10   [296]      1        1  [22]
```

I get following error:

```
predictions_target = predictions.groupby(['tree', 'cell'])    ['predict'].mean()
File "/usr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas    /core/groupby.py", line 1015, in mean
return self._python_agg_general(f)
File "/usr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 826, in _python_agg_general
return self._python_apply_general(f)
File "/usr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 698, in _python_apply_general
self.axis)
File "/usr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1577, in apply
splitter = self._get_splitter(data, axis=axis)
File "/usr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1563, in _get_splitter
comp_ids, _, ngroups = self.group_info
File "pandas/src/properties.pyx", line 34, in pandas.lib.cache_readonly.__get__ (pandas/lib.c:44222)
File "/usr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1670, in group_info
comp_ids, obs_group_ids = self._get_compressed_labels()
File "/usr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1677, in _get_compressed_labels
all_labels = [ping.labels for ping in self.groupings]
File "/usr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2308, in labels
self._musr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2319, in _make_labels
labels, uniques = algos.factorize(self.grouper, sort=self.sort)
File "/usr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 313, in factorize
labels = table.get_labels(vals, uniques, 0, na_sentinel, True)
File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 843, in     pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_labels (pandas/hashtable.c:14831)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'memmap'
```

Comment: Maybe need `predictions.list1 = predictions.list1.apply(tuple)` and `predictions.list2 = predictions.list2.apply(tuple)` if values are list of `memmap array`s

Comment: The best is add some small data sample - 4-5 rows, thanks.

Comment: This is almost but not quite a minimal working example...

Comment: I have Edited the question and added more information!